# Sorting Algorithms - Methods

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, sorting

I have to implement three different sorting algorithms using an Object-Oriented Approach and I have been thinking of the best method to combat this.

Basically, I think it should look like this:

-> Sort (Class, interface, Polymorphic)

Inherit:

-> Bubble Sort

-> Insertion Sort

-> QuickSort

If each of the sorts have the same interface then it would be easier to access the different methods of sorting, thus, meaning that when I come to add other sorting algorithms, I can easily implement them into the current design and class structure.

My questions are:

- Is this a good approach to use?
- Is there scope for me to use Templates? I.e. if I wanted to use Bubble, it would call the bubble sort, if I wanted to use Insertion it would call Insertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested use an interface (pure virtual class)

**Interface Method:**

```
class sort_algorithm_interface {
public:
    virtual void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const  = 0;
};

class BubbleSort : public sort_algorithm_interface {
public:
    virtual void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};

class InsertionSort: public sort_algorithm_interface {
public:
    virtual void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};

class QuickSort: public sort_algorithm_interface {
public:
    virtual void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};
```

Now when you want to sort you simple do the following:

```
sort_algorithm_interface& s = QuickSort(input);
s.sort(input);
```

**Template Method:**

```
class BubbleSort  {
public:
    void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};

class InsertionSort {
public:
    void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};

class QuickSort {
public:
    void sort(std::vector<int>& input) const {/* sort the input */}
};

template<typename Sort>
class MySort {
    void sort(std::vector<int>& input) {
        Sort s;
        s.sort(begin, end);
    }
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
MySort<QuickSort> s;
s.sort(input);
```

Comment: Thank you :) In "algorithm" would I need to create/ objects for each of the bubble sort, insertion sorts etc..? ... I would like to use Templates, if not for triggering which sort to compute but the data type of the sorted data

Comment: Thank you :)! So for the Template method, BubbleSort etc.. will still inherit from Sort?

Comment: Nope, `sort_algorithm_interface` does not need anything else. You only need to add code where is says `/* sort the input */`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can implement the 'Template Method' without the use of creating an abstract class?

Comment: @Phorce no inheritance in the template method. Just implement the sort function for bubble sort and  `MySort<BubbleSort> s; s.sort` will sort your data using buble sort ;

Comment: @Phorce Yes. you can use the template method without an abstract class.

Comment: That is great :)! I'm learning these things, so, final question.. Which do you think is the best implementation of this? The template method, or, the abstract (inheritance) method?

Comment: @Phorce The template method is a bit cleaner for me. But that's just a personal choice. It depends on what you prefer.

Comment: All the sort methods should be const. Your version using polymorphic types does not need to use pointers (just use references). Though I see little reason to limit your interface to vectors. Use iterators like all normal C++ interfaces. Also there is no way to sort user defined types that do not have an explicit `operator<`. All in all this is a very disappointing answer.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for the input I took it into consideration. But based on level of the question the limitations on the interface is acceptable. Your free to post a more complete answer.

Comment: Sorry but @ahenderson answer was very clear and helpful (hence the accepted answer) I learnt a lot, and I use vectors a lot so that was even more helpful. So thank you for answering this :)!

Answer (score 5):

`Sort` should be an interface or an abstract class, whereas bubble / insertion / quick-sort should be implementations / concrete classes.

It's also worth learning about the following:

**Strategy Pattern:**

[image: Strategy Pattern Diagram]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

and

**State Pattern:**

[image: State Pattern Diagram]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

As for templates, I don't think it's worth it in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this in C++ is via templates.

Sorting something is an algorithm, and it generally has little to no persistent state.  A sort isn't an object -- it is a function on data (which may be objects).

The `std` library already has a sort, with this signature:

```
template<typename I, typename C = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type> >
void sort(I begin, I end, C comp = C());
```

The iterators `begin` and `end` denote a range of values to be sorted, and comp is a functor (or function) that when passed two elements of the range of values tells you if the first one is less than the second.

To use this on a `std::vector`, you'd do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> myVector; // assume it has some data in it
sort( myVector.begin(), myVector.end() );
```

The std::sort is (usually?) a quicksort.  But the interface works for quick, bubble and insertion sort.

The big advantage of this approach is that one sort can use another.  As an example, while a quicksort is faster on large data sets, often on small data sets the simplicity of insertion sort wins (lower constant factor, even with the n^2 overhead).  So by writing your sorts like this, quicksort's recursive calls can instead become insertion sort when the number of elements is small.

Now, if you need run-time substitution of which algorithm you are using, you'll need to pin down what iterators you are using, and maybe even what comparitor.  This can be done with either a common function signature (what I'd do), or a base class with a pure virtual interface (which I would advise against).  Note that the overhead for a run-time chosen comparitor is non-trivial, however.  The overhead from a fixed iterator choice, or from a pointer-to-function or virtual method call, so long as it isn't done in the recursive calls of your algorithm, will be pretty cheap for any reasonable sized container.